# Inner Joins over Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

I think, I could have a misconception, how join works on multiple tables. Lets say you have three tables A, B, C and you need to join them.

Here is the V1

```
SELECT A.NAME AS name1
    ,B.NAME AS name2
    ,C.NAME AS name3
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN C
    ON B.id = C.id
```

Here is V2

```
SELECT A.NAME AS name1
    ,D.NAME AS name2
    ,D.NAME AS name3
FROM A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.NAME AS name2
        ,C.NAME AS name3
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C
        ON B.id = C.id
    ) AS D
    ON A.id = D.id
```

Is there any performance difference between the two versions?
Even though the first query looks cleaner, I need to build a Query Builder UI, restricting joins to only 2 tables helps.

Comment: Well, for one, the second query would fail as you aren't selecting the `Id` in the inner query.  But more importantly, these are not the same query.  In the first one, you are relating `A` to `B` and `A` to `C`.  In the second, you are relating `B` to `C`, which was not a defined relationship in the first query.  Not only that, but the second version is much more difficult to read/understand.  You should stick with the first version - it's cleaner, and easier to understand.

Comment: @Siyual - isn't there a B to C relationship implicit in the two joins - wouldn't JOIN B ON A.id=B.id JOIN C ON A.id=C.id give the same results as JOIN B ON A.id=B.id JOIN C ON B.id=C.id

Comment: @PaulF The only way to infer that a B-to-C relationship exists in that scenario is if you are joining the tables on the `ID` field for all three (which, is exactly as his example has it, though this looks like dummy code, rather than what he's actually using).  *However*, I highly doubt that you'll need to do a join across three tables where each of their primary keys are the same.  If that's the case, then yes, you can infer a B-to-C relation.  But otherwise, you cannot make that connection.

Comment: @Siyual, you are right, it's dummy code.

Comment: In the second fragment, you probably meant: `... ,D.name2 AS name2
    ,D.name3 AS name3` ; otherwise the queries are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a problem with subselects is that it can require the RDBMS to create a temporary table to fulfill the subselect - and on a large enough table this can be a serious expense - and potentially can't use any indexes on the subselect to optimize the query, and then you're scanning the table.

Of course, the DDL and size of the tables aren't included, so the best way is to have Postgres explain what it plans to do and compare/contrast.